# Change contact form to email based on selection?

Tags: forms, emails

I am attempting to change the email a custom contact form is sent to based on what selection the user makes when filling out the form. Is there a way to do this in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to make behave like its D7 incarnation without some custom code. You might, however, find this [issue on d.o.](https://www.drupal.org/node/1997692) useful; it contains a patch that adds a customizable block which lets you select a contact form (and thus recipient) to use.