# How to change the email recipient for contact form

Tags: 8, emails

On a Drupal 8 site, I have a content type called TeamMember which has an email field.  From the view where I show all the TeamMembers, I'd like to link to a form where the user can email that person directly.  Is there a way to customize the recipient of the email from a contact form?

Answer (score 2):

What we do in a few places is to have a hidden reference field to the team node in your contact message entity.

Then you pre-fill that when displaying the contact form and later on in hook_mail_alter(), use that information to change the recipient.

Requires a bit of custom code but then you don't have to create a lot of contact forms.

Comment: In my opinion this is also the only solution for creating forms with different recipients depending on the selected message subject.

Answer (score 1):

Contact forms in D8 don't have [customizable recipients out of the box](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/204222/change-contact-form-to-email-based-on-selection/204398#204398) so you're going to need some sort of workaround.

A couple of paths that you could take:

1. Treat your *TeamMember* not as *Node* entities, but as *User* entities. Use their profile page (**/user/X**) as the content page and use the personal contact form (**/user/X/contact**) as the per-*TeamMember* contact form.
2. Keep the *TeamMember*, but create a unique contact form for each *TeamMember*. On the *TeamMember* node type, create a Link field that links to each unique contact form you've built.